# iReport activate a jdbc connection

Tags: jdbc, ireport

I use iReport 4.0. After restarting windows I get error:

```
Error: the active connection is not of type jdbc. activate a jdbc connection first
```

how can I activate connection?

Comment: What is the type of connection (*jdbc*, *JSON*, etc.)? You can see [Get activate a JDBC connection when trying to read fields from JSON dataset](http://jasperforge.org/questions/540918/get-activate-jdbc-connection-when-trying-read-fields-json-dataset) post

Comment: Did you check this connection with Java code, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the pain killer below. This will figure out your sorrow.

Click that button in orange square and then in the opening popup, 
click new and then modify your jdbc settings.(driver, url, usrname, pwd etc...)

[here is the pain killer http://www.resimagaci.com/img/jp10jd.png](http://www.resimagaci.com/img/jp10jd.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the main toolbar,

report databases - click on new - select "Database JDBC Connection" - select appropriate DB (postgre, mysql, MS SQL, Oracle, etc).- type your schema name along with the url - type user & Pwd - click on test. It should work. Let me know in case if you need help.

Here is the link with nice explanation. Hope it will help you!

[click here.](https://www.netiq.com/documentation/idm401/reporting/data/bpbyf5y.html)

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me, I clicked on the "Report Datasources" button of the toolbar, and I saw that the "Samples" database was not the default one. I selected it to be the default one, I closed the window and... iReports worked as it was expected.